# Why are there multiple tables in WordPress, and why is it only reading the wrong/last one?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a database that's already been functioning well. I downloaded it, and now I'm trying to upload it to a new WordPress site.

Once the database is successfully loaded, the site still gives the default "Hello World" post.

I checked what's going on in the database, and there's wp_post, wp_2_post, wp_3_post, wp_4_post, and wp_5_post that include my data. But in wp_6_post it includes the default Hello World post, and it seems to only care about #6.

Why are there multiple tables like this, and why is it only reading the wrong/last one

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had wordpress network (multisite) with many blogs (6, in your case). On new machine you didn't configure it to work in network mode.

Add to your wp-config.php:

`define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );`

Comment: define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
I already have these two lines.